# How to delete all documents in DocumentDB using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have one collection user, which has many different properties.

Q.1 I want to run query with specific query and delete all those documents using nodejs, how can I do that?

Q.2 if I want to delete all documents using nodejs, how can I do this?

```
async.forEach(orders, function(order, callback) {
                client.deleteDocument(colle._self,order, function(err, success) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    } else {
                        callback(null, success);
                    }
                });
            }, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return respondFailed(res, { 'message': err }, 400);
                } else {
                    respondSuccess(res, null, 0, { message: 'All Orders deleted.' });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far and what are the issues you're running into.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Seems like you know how to delete documents, based on your code snippet. Is there a particular problem you're running into? Are you struggling with it in a client app? In a stored procedure? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: would it not be easier to delete the whole collection, and perhaps create a new one if you still need it?

Comment: @hsulriksen collections are billed hourly (that's the smallest time unit). So, a collection delete + re-create might not be practical, costwise, especially if performing this action repeatedly (e.g. unit testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your concern. finally I found my mistake.

In my code I was passing coll._self collection link instead of docu._self link.

```
async.forEach(orders, function(order, callback) {
            client.deleteDocument(order._self,order, function(err, success) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    callback(null, success);
                }
            });
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return respondFailed(res, { 'message': err }, 400);
            } else {
                respondSuccess(res, null, 0, { message: 'All Orders deleted.' });
            }
        });
```

Comment: This seems very inefficient solution when you have to delete 100s of document. Is it the only solution documentDB offers?

Comment: @Amitava I did find only this solution if you have better than this kindly let me know. It would be good for me dear.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a simple example of bulk delete.
Here is a similar solution working with the @azure/cosmos sdk:

```
  const { resources: users } = await container.items
    .query({
      query: "SELECT * from u"
    })
    .fetchAll();

  users.map(async usr => {
    await container.item(usr.id, usr.pk).delete()
  })
```